# Disnake/discord.py indefinitely await reponse

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I create a button and handle the callback or send a message and await a reaction in discord with my python bot, this seems to be limited in time. Sometimes after ~ 1hour, the bot doesn't register reactions anymore. For sure once I restart the bot, the connection is lost and it won't register the interaction anymore.

However, I have seen bots in discord that always react to a button, no matter how long ago that button was created. Is there a way to achieve this? Do I have to periodically "reconnect" the bot to the buttons it created?

Simple example:

```
class ButtonView(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Hi", style=ButtonStyle.red)
    async def first_button(
        self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction
    ):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Button clicked.")

class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
       
    @commands.slash_command() 
    async def test(self, inter):
        await inter.send("Button!", view=ButtonView())
```

-> In this example the bot won't react to the button click anymore after some time has passed or I restarted the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands


# Define a simple View that persists between bot restarts
# In order a view to persist between restarts it needs to meet the following conditions:
# 1) The timeout of the View has to be set to None
# 2) Every item in the View has to have a custom_id set
# It is recommended that the custom_id be sufficiently unique to
# prevent conflicts with other buttons the bot sends.
# For this example the custom_id is prefixed with the name of the bot.
# Note that custom_ids can only be up to 100 characters long.
class PersistentView(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @disnake.ui.button(
        label="Green", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="persistent_view:green"
    )
    async def green(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("This is green.", ephemeral=True)

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Red", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="persistent_view:red")
    async def red(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("This is red.", ephemeral=True)

    @disnake.ui.button(
        label="Grey", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="persistent_view:grey"
    )
    async def grey(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("This is grey.", ephemeral=True)


class PersistentViewBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned)
        self.persistent_views_added = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.persistent_views_added:
            # Register the persistent view for listening here.
            # Note that this does not send the view to any message.
            # In order to do this you need to first send a message with the View, which is shown below.
            # If you have the message_id you can also pass it as a keyword argument, but for this example
            # we don't have one.
            self.add_view(PersistentView())
            self.persistent_views_added = True

        print(f"Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})")
        print("------")


bot = PersistentViewBot()


@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def prepare(ctx: commands.Context):
    """Starts a persistent view."""
    # In order for a persistent view to be listened to, it needs to be sent to an actual message.
    # Call this method once just to store it somewhere.
    # In a more complicated program you might fetch the message_id from a database for use later.
    # However this is outside of the scope of this simple example.
    await ctx.send("What's your favourite colour?", view=PersistentView())


bot.run("token")
```

This code comes from [disnake repository](https://github.com/DisnakeDev/disnake/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py)

Comment: for some reason, I didn't manage to get this working on the first try, but now it works! I can confirm that after disconnecting and reconnecting the bot, it still responds to the buttons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most likely that your internet has a connection issue, and that you're disconnecting without noticing.

That was happening to me, so I added on_disconnect and on_resumed bot events that were just simple print statements so that I would be able to check on if that was the source of the issue.

```
bot: commands.Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
bot.time = time.time()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")
    print('TesterBot is ready starting at ' + time.ctime(bot.time))

@bot.event
async def on_disconnect():
    uptimedelta = time.time() - bot.time
    print('TesterBot is disconnected at ' + time.ctime(bot.time) + '. Testerbot has been up for ' + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=uptimedelta)))

@bot.event
async def on_resumed():
    uptimedelta = time.time() - bot.time
    print("TesterBot reconnected " + time.ctime(bot.time) + '. Testerbot has been up for ' + str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=uptimedelta)))

@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    print('TesterBot is connected starting at ' + time.ctime(time.time()))
```

Just basic stuff like that helped reveal that the problem was that my machine was dropping the connection. It was a physical issue with my internet, not a coding error or misunderstanding of the api or library.

Comment: You are right, I'm sure that's the case. But realistically speaking, when I host a bot for weeks, the connection might get interrupted at some point. So my question is whether it's possible to reconnect the bot to the buttons (potentially on multiple discord servers) after that happened?

Answer (score 0):

await inter.response.defer([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svqt5.png))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).